# If statement is supposed to change integer, but when used in printf * doesn't change

Tags: c++

I've printed a pyramid using printf *width specifier, for loops, and an if statement:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int sizeOfPyramid, numberOfDots;
    char dots = '.';

     cout << "Enter size of Pyramid: \n";
        cin >> sizeOfPyramid; //Gets the size of the pyramid


        for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfPyramid + 1; i++) {
            numberOfDots = i;
            cout << i;
            for (int r = 0; r < 2 * i + 1; r++) {
                if (r > 0) { numberOfDots = sizeOfPyramid + 1; }
                printf("%*c", sizeOfPyramid + 1 - numberOfDots, dots);
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
}
```

What I want to know is why you need the line below and how it changes the printf's width parameter:

> if(r > 0) {numberOfDots = sizeOfPyramid + 1; }

If you input 3 as sizeOfPyramid, when you get to the line above, numberOfDots should get set to 4. If you cout numberOfDots after the if statement, number of dots is equal to 0, then 1, then 2, then 3 **(The values of i)**.

```
for (int r = 0; r < 2 * i + 1; r++) {
    if (r > 0) { numberOfDots = sizeOfPyramid + 1; }
        cout << numberOfDots;
        printf("%*c", sizeOfPyramid + 1 - numberOfDots, dots);
        }
```

Why is **numberOfDots = sizeOfPyramid + 1;** needed when it doesn't change numberOfDots? Shouldn't printf width = 3+1 - 4? If you remove it, then the program doesn't work as it is supposed to.

> This is how I explained the full code to myself it to myself -

- You enter 3
- The for loop runs and numberOfDots is set to i(0).
- The next for loop runs and is true so it moves onto the if statement.
- The if statement should set **numberOfDots = sizeOfPyramid + 1 (This should mean 4 = 3 + 1 if i'm not mistaken.)**
- Then the printf functiom is called *(I list exactly what i think each variable is)* **("%*c", 3 + 1 - 4, .)**

This is where I get confused. Shouldn't the width integer be equal to 0 if numberOfDots is 4 and 4 - 4 = 0? If the * is 0, the dots shouldn't be shifted over any spaces? Why does numberOfDots stay equal to i even after being set to a different value during the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement asks for `r > 0`.

The code is actually a bit confusing. It can be rewritten in a clearer fashion.

```
if (r == 0) { // leftmost dot.
    printf("%*c", 1 + sizeOfPyramid - numberOfDots, dots);
}else{ // other dots.
    printf("%c", dots);
}
```

In the first iteration for `r == 0` the left padding is added.

So in your explanation you make a mistake where you state

> - The next for loop runs and is true so it moves onto the if statement.
> - The if statement should set numberOfDots = sizeOfPyramid + 1 (This should mean 4 = 3 + 1 if i'm not mistaken.)

The if-statement executes every iteration except the first one.  The assignment made in the if-statement reverses the effect of the width specification in the `printf`. This is why I'm of the opinion the construct above is a lot easier to read.

It is difficult to simply describe the if-statement

```
if (r > 0) { 
    // cancel width calculation.
    numberOfDots = sizeOfPyramid + 1; 
}
```

because it works only in conjunction with the printf construct.

```
printf("%*c", sizeOfPyramid + 1 - numberOfDots, dots);
```

And this construct sets the padding space of the leftmost dot. On all other dots the width is zero, as you concluded in your post.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining everything so throughly! I can kind of gert a grasp on what you mean. As you could probably tell i'm not the most skilled programmer, and having someone like you to explain it for me is very helpful. Have a great day!